# What is meant by a blind write in a schedule?

Tags: transaction, jobs, database-theory, serialization

I know that every conflict-serialisable schedule is view-serialisable but the converse is not true. I read in a webpage that when a schedule is view-serialisable but not conflict-serialisable then there exist some blind writes. So what is a blind write?

Comment: Perhaps you should cite your source. Or provide excerpts.

Answer (score 8):

If there is no read that happens prior to the first write then it is said to be a *blind write*.

**Example.** Consider the following schedule:

[image]

- **W<sub>3</sub>(X)** is a blind write, as there is no read before write [R<sub>3</sub>(X) before W<sub>3</sub>(X)]
- **W<sub>2</sub>(X)** is not a blind write, as a read happens before write [R<sub>2</sub>(X) before W<sub>2</sub>(X)]

Answer (score -1):

A blind write is a write operation e.g. W(X) by a transaction Ti after which the attribute X is not read by a transaction but some other transaction Tj performs another write operation on attribute X. Thus, the write operation by Ti becomes blind write.

Comment: So, Ti's write operation is blind write? I think Tj's

Comment: do transactions such as T3 that only contain a blind write ever abort?

Answer (score -1):

If a transaction without reading a data item directly performs a write operations ,then it is Blind or Dirty Write.

```
   T-1          T-2
   R(A)
   W(A)
               R(A)
               W(A)
   R(B)
   W(B)--------|
               |
               |     
              W(B)  (In this it has directly performed W(B) without reading 
                     B i.e R(B) )
```

Comment: It's not clear how this answer is different from sharhp's answer.